# Azure Service Fabric + VS 2022 + .NET 7

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2022, azure-service-fabric

I want to create Azure Service Fabric App working with .NET 7. From what I understood from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-versions that latest version supports up to .NET 7.
I am working with **Visual Studio Professional 2022 (v. 17.8.0)** and installed:

- **Azure Service Fabric SDK 7.0.1949.9590**
- **Azure Service Fabric Runtime 10.0.1949.9590**

While creating a new project in VS (File > New > Project) and choosing Service Fabric Application, the latest framework option is .NET Framework 4.8 (as shown below)
[image]

I followed official article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started but it mentions VS 2017 and 2019. Is there anything else that I need to support .NET 7 in Azure Service Fabric template?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: You need to update your VS by enabling the .net 7 runtime in individual components.

Comment: You will get an option to select [CORE](https://i.imgur.com/AfSTcbs.png) in next step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the latest framework option is .NET Framework 4.8

In Visual Studio Installer, click on Modify option to check the Runtime versions.

[image]

- Install the required CORE Versions.

[image]

- Yes, when you check the Service Fabric Application, in the first template it shows only the framework version.
- Select any of the framework and click on any service under .NET Core.

[image]

- Click on `Create`, here you will get an option to select the .NET Core Version along with the template.

[image]

- You can also check the version of CORE in `.csproj` file of the Web App.

[image]

Refer this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/hosting-net-core-services-on-service-fabric/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20already%20have%20a%20service%20that%20targets.NETCoreApp,the%20Service%20Fabric%20SDK%20only%20supports.NET%20Framework%204.5.2.) by Mike Rousos for more details.

Comment: Thank you a lot for descriptive answer! I've already had "NET 7.0 Runtime" and "Service Fabric Tools" components installed but what I had to do finally was to update VS from v. 17.8.0 to v. 17.8.6 and then I finally got the new template o.O